# Use MarkupExtension in PriorityBinding

Tags: wpf, binding

**EDIT: TL/DR**
*You can use custom markup extensions in `PriorityBinding`. It likely gets highlighted with an error message and the designer might not show it at design time but it works like a charm at runtime. Seems to be an issue with the XAML designer or some other internal component.*

Well I have certain scenarios in our software where I need to display a translated string in case the binding returns null. Here my production number is set only at a certain point and until then I want to show "Unknown" translated in the user's language. For this we're using a custom markup which returns a binding to an intermediate object that supports translation.

Sadly `MarkupExtension` is inherited by `BindingBase` and not the other way around. So since `PriorityBinding` expects a collection of `BindingBase` I can't add my translation markup as fallback binding.

This is what I tried:

```
<PriorityBinding>
    <Binding Path="ProductionNumber" />
    <l:Translate Key="Unknown" Context="Common" />
</PriorityBinding>
```

So does anyone know how to work around this? Using `PriorityBinding` would be the easiest way to do this. Of course I could use a converter for this but then I would eliminate some essential features implemented in the markup which basically renders it useless.

Comment: Why can't you use a custom `Binding` implementation with the `TargetNullValue` property set?

Comment: I would need to provide a value each time `TargetNullValue` is used. Thus I have to override it which doesn't work as the base-class won't use it when implemented with `new`. And since the whole binding system is locked down, I can't override any logic for `Binding`... This way I end up having a static value, which won't change when I switch the language.

Comment: I don't follow. You can just set the `TargetNullValue`, or any other property, of each instance of the custom binding, can't you?

Comment: No. Our software works without having to restart. If I change the language, everything instantly is translated thanks to bindings. I can't just once set a fallback value as it would be similar to a one-time binding. Moreover does this `TranslateMarkup` implement logic which walks the logic tree in order to build the context-hierarchy (each element in XAML can have a *Context*-attached property which resolves to a full context path in the markup's `ProvideValue` method).

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Comment: How to achieve a binding with a fallback value that's functional of using custom logic not just a plain static value. Like PriorityBinding with a custom markup. The question is: Is there a workaround or is this completely limited by the capabilities of the WPF binding API? Most of the time there's someone who found a workaround.

Comment: @SharpShade, will `<Binding><Binding.Source><l:Translate Key="Unknown" Context="Common" /></Binding.Source></Binding>` work?

Comment: I tried this but it fails as `A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Source' property of type 'Binding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.`

Comment: Well, I just found out that it **does work**. It's obviously an issue of the XAML Designer or something underlying which marks it as invalid. But you **can** use custom markups in a `PriorityBinding`. It does not work in the designer, but at runtime it works like a charm.